# How can I place a series of boxes one right after the other in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way in PowerPoint to place a series of rectangular boxes right after each other so they form a continuous row? I know about distributing horizontally and aligning and snapping, but I don't see an option to place them after each other automatically, i.e. 'linearizing' them.

I do not want to change the sizes of the boxes, as they are fixed, just place them horizontally one right after the next, touching each other ever so slightly. And placing them individually by turning on snapping is too cumbersome because there are too many to be practical.

For ease, you can assume they are the same size, but I would also be interested to know if there's a way to do it if they are all different sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The manual way is to drag the boxes using the equidistant guides to evenly space out
the shapes. These guides will automatically appear when you drag the shape
(you'll see dotted lines) and the shapes will "snap together" when you align them
to the guides.

Otherwise, if feeling adventurous, you can use a VBA macro, which requires the
file to be `.pptm` rather than `.pptx`.

The following VBA macro will align all selected shapes to be vertically
aligned with the first-selected object and following it by order of selection:

```
Sub AlignMultipleShapes()

Dim shp   As Shape
Dim count As Integer
Dim curix As Integer
Dim topy  As Integer
Dim lastx As Integer

'Count How Many Shapes Are Selected
count = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.count

'Loop Through each selected Shape (align with first selected)
For curix = 1 To count
  If curix = 1 Then
    Set shp = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    topy = shp.top
    lastx = shp.Left + shp.Width
  Else
    Set shp = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange(curix)
    'Align Top
    shp.top = topy
    'Align Center (Vertical Center)
    shp.Left = lastx
    lastx = shp.Left + shp.Width
  End If
Next curix

End Sub
```

Useful references:

- [How to use VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) in PowerPoint](https://www.brightcarbon.com/blog/how-to-use-vba-in-powerpoint/)
- [PowerPoint VBA reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/powerpoint)